# Correctly declaring ConfigurationManager when connecting to database

Tags: vb.net, configurationmanager

How do I solve the error message "ConfigurationManager not declared" when used to connect to database?

Here is the line of code which gives the error:

```
SQLConnStr= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnStr").ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried to Add Reference

```
  `System.Configuration`
```

on you References Folder.

Just simply right click your references folder on your project then click add reference..
and then look for System.Configuration then ok.

then add

```
Imports System.Configuration
```

on your form

Change you app config to this:

```
<connectionStrings> 

<add name="SQLConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=HOTEL_MySQLSERVERR;Initial Catalog=GuestBooking;User ID=xyz;Password=xyz" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 

</connectionStrings>
```

//your app config name and connection string name must be the same

**add name="SQLConnStr"**

**ConnectionStrings("SQLConnStr").**

```
SQLConnStr= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnStr").ConnectionString
```

and have a look at this:

[Fix the Name ‘ConfigurationManager’ is Not Declared Error](http://www.howtodotnetnuke.com/Blogs/tabid/177/EntryId/11/Fix-the-Name-ConfigurationManager-is-Not-Declared-Error.aspx)

Regards

Comment: Try: Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnStr").ConnectionString.ToString()

Comment: i tried to hard code aswel now the error says "ConfigurationManager is not a member of configuration"

Comment: <connectionStrings>
        <add name="GuestBooking.My.MySettings.GuestBookingConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=HOTEL_MySQLSERVERR;Initial Catalog=GuestBooking;User ID=abcd;Password=abcd"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="GuestBooking.My.MySettings.Setting" connectionString="Data Source=HOTEL_MySQLSERVERR;Initial Catalog=GuestBooking;User ID=xyz;Password=xyz"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try removing and adding the reference again 
"System.Configuration.dll"
 Under Project > Add refrence > .Net > select System.Configuration

Comment: Crimsonland already posted this answer over 2 years ago. Why have you re-posted it? What new information does your answer add to this question?